# SVN Can't connect to host

Tags: svn

We have a SVN repository setup on a remote host server. We have a brand new Dev server which eventually I will be setting up our repository on there, but for now I am trying to export a project onto the dev server from SVN. When I try to do it, I get svn: Can't connect to host 'website.com': Connection timed out.

I can connect fine from any other server so I am assuming it must be something on the dev server, I am just not sure what setting might be blocking this. I can ping the server and that comes back with results, I thought maybe since it was a local network server, there might of been something blocking access to the external web.

I'm just looking for a few ideas as to what it might be.

Comment: this should go to www.serverfault.com :)
Anyway, have you checked that the port that SVN listens (3690 default) is not blocked at the router/firewall?

Comment: Firewall on the SVN Server or gateway server.

Comment: and also check that the SVN server isn't IP-restricted to your existing machines.

Comment: I will try and check that out now, I guess you are right I should of put this on serffault, forgot

Comment: Did you install and configure svn on it?  If not, have you confirmed that whoever set it up used the svnserve daemon?  Or did they set it up with webDAV which would require the http: protocol instead of svn:?

Comment: Amardeep, I think you are talking about the server that actually has the repository on it right? I know that has the svnserve daemon running on it.

Comment: @dan.codes: Yes, sorry, I meant the Dev server.  Also confirm that when you ping it by name you get the correct IP address.  If your DNS is not resolving the name it will resolve to some 'parking' machine which will ping fine but not respond on 3690.

Answer (score 8):

I just solve it by the commands below:
when starting a svn service, add the part "--listen-host 0.0.0.0" to your command, for example:

svnserve -d --listen-port 9803 --listen-host 0.0.0.0 -r /somewhere/somewhere

This is because unless explicitly stated, svnserve will listen for IPv6 connections where the IPv6 protocol is supported, which is true of Windows Vista, 7 and Server 2008, Maybe FreeBSD too.

My server has the FreeBSD os, I met with this problem this morning and solved it just now.

you can refer to this page:
[further info](http://www.renaissance-design.net/2010/installing-and-configuring-svnserve-and-tortoisesvn-on-windows/)

Comment: thank-you so much kaldr for answering this old problem.  i had this issue, found this question via google, and your advice fixed things for me.

Comment: @Bob, not quite, as people will come here via Google (like me) and seek resolution. Time doesn't count on the Internet.

Comment: @Veehmot - given the perspective of more time, you are absolutely right. Comment withdrawn.

Answer (score 2):

This may seem low level, but double check you are using the protocol to connect that the server is set up for (svn:// for svn, http:// for http, ssh+svn:// for svn over ssh) and double check your firewall settings.

SVN uses port 3690 if you are connecting using the SVN protocol (default for new setups), (obviously) port 80 for the HTTP protocol, and (again obviously) port 22 for the SSH protocol.

Comment: Sorry 3980 was a typo, correct one is 3690 - cat jumped on my keyboard :)

Answer (score 2):

If can telnet the ip and port, make sure

1. set the listen host to 0.0.0.0;
2. use the url svn://domain:port/ to connect the server

Answer (score 1):

In my case, at these days, the problem was that I was using `svn 1.7.x`, and this version throws this error when I try to use from command line.

I just try with `svn 1.8.x` and all worked fine, I can finally interact through command line without problem.

In case someone else face-off this problem, maybe this can helps.

Regards,

p.s. I am on Linux Centos 6.5.

Answer (score 0):

```
> sudo dnf install cyrus-sasl-md5
```

I had the same issue. For me, I needed to install the package cyrus-sasl-md5.

Without this package, svn has no way to ask for or store passwords, so it isn't able to find the server.